# Negating a Statement "At least K numbers are larger than W"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

What is the negation of  "At least $K$ numbers are larger than $W$"?

Suppose if we set $j=$ number of numbers larger than $W$. Then, $$j \ge K$$ which negates as, $$j<K$$
which translates to $$\text{at most }K\text{ numbers are larger than }W$$

Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: You are not quite negating the way one should when doing predicate calculus, but that aside: the negation of "there are at least $K$ integers greater than $W$" over the domain of the integers is "there are at most $K-1$ integers greater than $W$". Your inequalities, while not very well defined, give this; just note "at most" is inclusive while your inequality is not inclusive, so you must use $K-1$. You could also say "at most $K$ integers greater than $W$ exclusive", though this is sure to lead to confusion.

Comment: Thanks, it cleared me well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation may be given by

> Less than $K$ numbers are larger than $W$

or

> Not up to $K$ numbers are larger than $W$